# ({/* Code block */})(); what does this means in C#?

Tags: c#

I have seen code

```
(stringValue switch
 {
    "Add" => (Action) Add,
    "Subtract" => Subtract,
    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
 })();
```

what is the meaning of below syntax -
I mean to ask what does it mean when one write curly braces enclosed in
parentheses with (); at the end.

```
   ({
     /* Some lines of Code*/  
    })();
```

Comment: I'm confused... the thing you're asking about *doesn't appear* in the example you give; but... "// some lines of code" is a code-comment that is saying "there's more stuff that goes here, I haven't included it because it isn't relevant, or it needs to be added by someone else, for example: the OP"

Comment: It's a [Code comment](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/comments-in-C-Sharp/#:~:text=To%20code%20a%20comment%2C%20type,entire%20block%20of%20code%20statements.) It's meant for actual descriptive text in plain English. However, if the "comment" is actual c# code, it was "commented-out," i.e. rendered inactive quickly by a developer without losing the original source code. The compiler will ignore it.

Comment: By any chance: are Methods `Add` and `Subtract` in that class, that code is from? In that case the example code takes a string argument and uses that to determine a method to call and then calls it. (Talking about the example, only)

Comment: Must be the new switch syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions and creating an immediately invoked function expression (as Anu mentions in the answer)

Comment: When you write `({ // Some lines of Code })();`, do you mean `({ /* some code goes here */ })();`. If so, you've confused folks; in C#, everything after `//` is considered a comment

Comment: I am sorry about it...  I have changed my query

Answer (score 1):

Hope I have understood your question correctly.

This is an example to construct Immediately Invoked Function Expression or IIFE using C#.

The code given in OP is same as the following

```
 var action = stringValue switch // use switch over the string value to identify method to call
 {
   "Add" => (Action) Add,
    "Subtract" => Subtract,
    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
 };
 
 action();
```

Unlike having to explicitly declare a variable, the expression is evaluated directly in the version given in OP

Comment: Thanx.. I wanted to know about IIFE. I searched and got to know that it is javascript concept. But I couldn't get proper information on how and when to use it in C# code.. I would like to get more information about it..